# Python get nested dictionary value inside of list

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I get the start and end values in a dictionary named `my_dict` with this format:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(my_dict)

{'metadata': [{'filename': 'this_is_a_filename',
                  'filepath': 'this_is_a_filepath',
                  'location': 'this_is_a_location',
                  'time': {'end': 1489787859.905748,
                           'start': 1489787843.980593},
                  'place':
                  etc...
```

Where:
`my_dict` is a dictionary
`metadata` is a dictionary in `my_dict`
`time` is a dictionary in a list whose index can change

I've tried:

```
for key in my_dict['metadata'][0]:
    if key == "time":
        print key("end")
```

but key is a string not an object so key("end") does not work. I've searched everything and tried for hours but cannot figure this out.

EDIT:

The user Dan answered correctly below within less than 3 minutes of asking the question :)

```
for d in my_dict.get('metadata', []):
    t = d.get('time', {})
    print t.get('end')
    print t.get('start')
```

Comment: you can just do `my_dict['metadata'][0]['time']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for d in my_dict.get('metadata', []):
    t = d.get('time', {})
    print t.get('end')
    print t.get('start')
```